# How do I find a second-order homogenous linear ODE given the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question gives me a basis of $\cos(5x)$ and $\sin(5x)$. Solving the IVP I get,

$y=3\cos(5x)-\sin(5x)$
given
$y(0)=3$, $y'(0)=-5$

but how do I work backwards and get the ODE for this question? Similar questions to this already posted have $e$s in their basis, so I didn't apply their methods of solution to my question.

Comment: $y'' + 25 y = 0$

Comment: I already know the solution; I wish to know how.

Answer (score 2):

If $y=f(x)$ is a solution of a homogeneous second-order linear differential equation with constant coefficients, $a y'' + c y' + d y = 0$, that says $a f'' + b f' + c f = 0$.  So write out $f'$ and $f''$, plug in to the equation and see if you can find $a,b,c$ that make this work.  In this case you'll get an expression involving $\cos(5x)$ and $\sin(5x)$.  You want this to work for all $x$, so both the coefficients of $\cos(5x)$ and of $\sin(5x)$ should end up as  $0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$y=C\cos(5x)+C_0\sin(5x)$$
That you can rewrite as:
$$y=Ae^{5ix}+Be^{-5ix}$$
The characteristic polynomial has roots $\pm 5i$:
$$(r-5i)(r+5i)=0$$
$$r^2+25=0$$
From this you deduce the DE:
$$y''+25y=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$y=3\cos 5x -\sin 5x\implies y'=-15\sin 5x -5\cos 5x \implies y''=-75 \cos 5x+25\sin 5x= -25 y$$